# Accessing image file uploaded in app folder from URL in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have uploaded my image files under `"app/upload"` directory of `symfony2`.

And I have defined my domain root "`web`" directory in `vhosts`.

How do I have to access those images from browser's address bar, something like, `"my-domain.loc/app_dev.php/upload/img-001.jpg"?`

Answer (score 2):

You do not, everything that is publicly accessible should be in your **web** directory not your **app** directory.

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html#the-web-directory

Comment: Understand now. Thanks.

Comment: @heinwintsoe No problem! Good luck on your symfony2 journey!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [StremedResponse](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/StreamedResponse.html):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

protected function createSendFileResponse(File $file)
{
    $response = StreamedResponse::create(function() use ($file) { readfile($file); });
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', $file->getMimeType());
    return $response;
}
```

and use it in your controller (e.g. like a service) with a concrete route.

It is common to use `app/var/foo` to save uploaded files.